# CSS Properties for Background Image do not work on FireFox

Tags: css

I have a webpage where I want to show the background image @ the bottom right corner of the page. For this I have the following code:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('img_tree.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom right;
}
```

This code works fine in IE. But in FireFox, the image is shown at the 'top' right.

Please suggest.

Regards
- Ashish

Comment: Don't put the stuff inside: url(...) in quotes. As the poster below noted, just url(img_tree.png); is appropriate.

Comment: @silky quotes are optional - I'd say it's good practice to put them in

Comment: It's optional, and only *required* if the filename includes spaces so `url(img_tree.png)` is fine, but `url('img tree.png')` would need the quotes. Other than that? To-may-to, to-mah-to. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html, body { height:100%; }

body {
    background:url(img_tree.png) no-repeat bottom right;
}
```

I think it's just that your page isnt taking up the full viewport height, which the 100% height on body/html does.

Comment: Position is fixed now, however now the image goes a little too low in (shows a vertical scroll-bar). You can see the screen-shot below (see the bottom right corner) 

http://i32.tinypic.com/2rf6a8o.jpg

Comment: The scrollbar is due to some non-zero default padding or margin. `html, body { height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use

background: url(img_tree.png) right bottom no-repeat;

This works fine in IE and firefox